# How to use global environment properties in the pluginManagement of an settings.gradle?

Tags: gradle, groovy, gradle-plugin

Global Gradle.properties:

```
USERNAME=<username>
PASSWORD=<password>
```

Gradle Settings file:

```
pluginManagement {
    plugins {
        id 'plugin.plugin.plugin' version '0.0.1'
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials{
                username = "${USERNAME}" != "" ? "${USERNAME}" : System.getenv('USERNAME')
                password = "${PASSWORD}" != "" ? "${PASSWORD}" : System.getenv('PASSWORD')
            }
            url = '<custom plugin repository>'
        }
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

The error i get when i build this project:

```
    * Exception is:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/plugin/devel/internal/precompiled/FirstPassPrecompiledScript
```

How can I successfully use global properties inside the pluginManagement in the settings.gradle file?

Comment: It seems that it just work with gradle 7.4.2 and properties added to `$GRADLE_HOME/gradle.properties`.

Comment: I am using gradle 7.4.2

Comment: please provide an example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: my code is there, I cannot give an example as I cannot share the project.

Comment: Just don’t be funny ;) I do not ask to copy the code from repo. But to prepare a demo that shows the problem. Like here, but for answers: https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

why to not use a method for getting the values like this:

```
artifactoryUser = getConfigurationProperty("ARTIFACTORY_USER", "artifactoryUser", null)
artifactoryPwd = getConfigurationProperty("ARTIFACTORY_PWD", "artifactoryPwd", null)
```

And `getConfigurationProperty` will look for system environment variable called `ARTIFACTORY_USER` then it will check `gradle.properties` for a `artifactoryUser` variable, Else will return default value.

```
String getConfigurationProperty(String envVar, String sysProp, String defaultValue) {
    def result = System.getenv(envVar) ?: project.findProperty(sysProp)
    result ?: defaultValue
}
```

Then in the repositories section

```
    maven {
        url = mavenRepoURL
        credentials {
            username artifactoryUser
            password artifactoryPwd
        }
    }
```

Comment: pluginManagement has be defined on line 1 of the settings.gradle, so unfortunately this would not work

Comment: Then why don't you move the username/password inside pluginManagement block ?
like `userName = project.findProperty(USERNAME)` , will this work?

Comment: project does not exist the settings.gradle file unfortunatly, unless I'm doing something wrong